# How to set image at bottom of Imageview, but at image source not image size

Tags: android, imageview

Now I am getting the output like this(Text is at bottom of the screen),

[image]

But I want output like the following image.

[image]

This is my XML code:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/rlBottom"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/coringImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/img_electricity"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fdc_tvUnGeneration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fdc_tvAVGeneration"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set margin bottom  to fdc_tvUnGeneration as per requirement

Comment: set margin bottom to fdc_tvUnGeneration is not working because in different screen it image has different size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code...

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rlBottom">

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/coringImage"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/img_electricity"/>

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/fdc_tvUnGeneration"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
       android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
       android:textColor="@color/color_white"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
       android:layout_below="@+id/fdc_tvAVGeneration"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`android:scaleType="fitXY"`
in your imageview

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.us.upen.mymusicplayer.ui.SplashActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/coringImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/img_electricity" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fdc_tvUnGeneration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/coringImage"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I checked this

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Remove attribute `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from `TextView`

**2.** Add attribute `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/coringImage"` and `android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"` to `TextView`.

FYI, here I used bottom margin as 10dp, you can change it as per your needs.

**Here is an example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/rlBottom">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coringImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fdc_tvUnGeneration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/coringImage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="I am a Text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" from textview

```
       <RelativeLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/coringImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/wood01_c_pia" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fdc_tvUnGeneration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/coringImage"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="test"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</RelativeLayout>
```